# Formatting sub figures which use tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, formatting

I'm writing an exam paper for a friend's tutoring business. One of the questions is going to be on velocity-time graphs. I wanted the 4 graphs to show up in a 2x2 grid but using the code below they are showing up in a 4x1 structure. How can I change this?

The code:

```
\question[1] A car, initially at rest, sets off a 2m/s and travels at this velocity for 2 seconds. It then decelerates a 1m/s$^2$ to 0m/s. It then accelerates at -0.5m/s$^2$ until it reaches a velocity of -1m/s. It stays at this velocity for 2 seconds before coming instantly to rest. Which of the following velocity-time graphs represents the motion of the car?

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.2\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.25]
        \draw [gray] (0,-3) grid (8,3);
        \draw [red] (0,2) -- (2,2) -- (4,0) -- (6,-1) -- (6,0) -- (8,0);
        \draw[->] (0,0) -- (8,0);
        \draw[->] (0,-3) -- (0,3);
        \draw (0,2) node [left] {velocity(m/s)};
        \draw (8,-1) node [right] {time(s)};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:a}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.2\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.25]
        \draw [gray] (0,-3) grid (8,3);
        \draw [red] (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (4,-2) -- (6,-3) -- (6,-3) -- (8,-3);
        \draw[->] (0,0) -- (8,0);
        \draw[->] (0,-3) -- (0,3);
        \draw (0,2) node [left] {velocity(m/s)};
        \draw (8,-1) node [right] {time(s)};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:b}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.2\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.25]
        \draw [gray] (0,-3) grid (8,3);
        \draw [red] (0,2) -- (2,2) -- (4,0) -- (6,1) -- (6,0) -- (8,0);
        \draw[->] (0,0) -- (8,0);
        \draw[->] (0,-3) -- (0,3);
        \draw (0,2) node [left] {velocity(m/s)};
        \draw (8,-1) node [right] {time(s)};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:c}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.2\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.25]
        \draw [gray] (0,-3) grid (8,3);
        \draw [red] (0,-2) -- (2,-2) -- (4,0) -- (6,-1) -- (6,0) -- (8,0);
        \draw[->] (0,0) -- (8,0);
        \draw[->] (0,-3) -- (0,3);
        \draw (0,2) node [left] {velocity(m/s)};
        \draw (8,-1) node [right] {time(s)};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:d}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Remove blank line between firs and second and also between third and fourth sub figures.

Comment: Replace the empty lines between the first and second, and third and fourth subfigure by `\quad`?

Comment: that tikzpicture is part of the main document flow, it shouldn't be in a `figure` environment

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using the `exam` documentclass, I have made the following MWE. I have removed the empty lines between first and second as well as between the third and last `subfigure`. I have also increased  the width of the subfigures to `0.5\textwidth` (Make sure to add a `%` after `\end{subfigure}`). Additionally, I have added the `\centering` command into all `subfigure` environment and changed the vertical alignment of the third subfigure from `t` to `b`. Lastly, I have also introduced the `siunitx` package for a more uniform representation (and easy customization)  of the numerical values and their units.

[image]

```
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question[1] A car, initially at rest, sets off a \SI{2}{\meter\per\second} and travels at this velocity for 2 seconds. It then decelerates a \SI{1}{\meter\per\second\squared} to \SI{0}{\meter\per\second}. It then accelerates at \SI{-0.5}{\meter\per\second\squared} until it reaches a velocity of \SI{-1}{\meter\per\second}. It stays at this velocity for 2 seconds before coming instantly to rest. Which of the following velocity-time graphs represents the motion of the car?

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth} \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.25]
        \draw [gray] (0,-3) grid (8,3);
        \draw [red] (0,2) -- (2,2) -- (4,0) -- (6,-1) -- (6,0) -- (8,0);
        \draw[->] (0,0) -- (8,0);
        \draw[->] (0,-3) -- (0,3);
        \draw (0,2) node [left] {velocity(m/s)};
        \draw (8,-1) node [right] {time(s)};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:a}
    \end{subfigure}%
%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth} \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.25]
        \draw [gray] (0,-3) grid (8,3);
        \draw [red] (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (4,-2) -- (6,-3) -- (6,-3) -- (8,-3);
        \draw[->] (0,0) -- (8,0);
        \draw[->] (0,-3) -- (0,3);
        \draw (0,2) node [left] {velocity(m/s)};
        \draw (8,-1) node [right] {time(s)};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:b}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth} \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.25]
        \draw [gray] (0,-3) grid (8,3);
        \draw [red] (0,2) -- (2,2) -- (4,0) -- (6,1) -- (6,0) -- (8,0);
        \draw[->] (0,0) -- (8,0);
        \draw[->] (0,-3) -- (0,3);
        \draw (0,2) node [left] {velocity(m/s)};
        \draw (8,-1) node [right] {time(s)};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:c}
    \end{subfigure}%
%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth} \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.25]
        \draw [gray] (0,-3) grid (8,3);
        \draw [red] (0,-2) -- (2,-2) -- (4,0) -- (6,-1) -- (6,0) -- (8,0);
        \draw[->] (0,0) -- (8,0);
        \draw[->] (0,-3) -- (0,3);
        \draw (0,2) node [left] {velocity(m/s)};
        \draw (8,-1) node [right] {time(s)};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:d}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

As supplement to @leandris answer, some off-topic changes which my be useful to you. They are marked (in the first sub figure) by `% <---` ...

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

    \begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\linewidth} % <---
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5] % <---
    \draw [gray] (0,-3) grid (8,3);
    \draw [red] (0,2) -- (2,2) -- (4,0) -- (6,-1) -- (6,0) -- (8,0);
    \draw[->] (0, 0) --  (8,0) node [right] {time (s)}; % <---
    \draw[->] (0,-3) -- node [above,sloped] {velocity (m/s)} (0,3); % <---
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:a}
\end{subfigure}
\hfil % <---
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\linewidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
    \draw [gray] (0,-3) grid (8,3);
    \draw [red] (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (4,-2) -- (6,-3) -- (6,-3) -- (8,-3);
    \draw[->] (0, 0) --  (8,0) node [right] {time (s)};;
    \draw[->] (0,-3) -- node [above,sloped] {velocity (m/s)} (0,3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:b}
\end{subfigure}

\bigskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\linewidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
    \draw [gray] (0,-3) grid (8,3);
    \draw [red] (0,2) -- (2,2) -- (4,0) -- (6,1) -- (6,0) -- (8,0);
    \draw[->] (0, 0) --  (8,0) node [right] {time (s)};;
    \draw[->] (0,-3) -- node [above,sloped] {velocity (m/s)} (0,3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:c}
\end{subfigure}
\hfil
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\linewidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
    \draw [gray] (0,-3) grid (8,3);
    \draw [red] (0,-2) -- (2,-2) -- (4,0) -- (6,-1) -- (6,0) -- (8,0);
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (8,0);
    \draw[->] (0,-3) -- (0,3);
    \draw[->] (0, 0) --  (8,0) node [right] {time (s)};;
    \draw[->] (0,-3) -- node [above,sloped] {velocity (m/s)} (0,3);
   \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:d}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

Note: please always provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document, which we can compile as it is.